# Load report after page is loaded

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using apex 4.2.6.

I have few questions.
When you request apex page through your browser, and that page has one report on it.

How does apex handle rendering that page ?
Does it generate report prior to rendering of page ,or it only generates the report after loading of page is done?

Can I start processing of my report **after** page was loaded?

So a user would click on a link that would lead him to a page with report. His page would load pretty fast and then he would see like a spinning wheel on a report region until it's done with rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on Debug mode (by click on Debug button at Developer panel OR by modify URL - set fifth element to YES), then load your page, click Show Debug at Developer panel and choose session. Its shows steps order and how much time each step proccesed.

About APEX URL syntax: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03017

Also you can set some condition (Request = Expression 1 for example) and render your report region only if condition meets.

**EDIT:**
If you want refresh region only, without reload whole page, try this:

1. I create example https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54028:2
2. Make some hidden item, set its value in unconditional Init Process to NO or 0.
3. Make a report region, with one addititional WHERE condition hidden item = 'YES' or 1.
4. Make a button, Action: Redirect to URL, URL: #
5. Make a Dynamic Action, that firing onClick this button and 3 True Actions: 
   Set hidden item value to YES or 1, Submit hidden item value, Reload your region

Comment: If I create a condition that is based on a request , that would mean that in order to get report rendered I would have to refresh the page with new request, right? I don't want to refresh the page.

Comment: Ok I understand that, but how do you stop report rendering on load in that case?